# How does Symfony controller as service work with __invoke method?

Tags: service, symfony

For example, in the following code:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/patients", service="bundle1.controller.patient.index")
 */
final class IndexController
{
    private $router;
    private $formFactory;
    private $templating;
    private $patientFinder;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router, FormFactoryInterface $formFactory, EngineInterface $templating, PatientFinder $patientFinder)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
        $this->templating = $templating;
        $this->patientFinder = $patientFinder;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("", name="patients_index")
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $request) : Response
    {
        $form = $this->formFactory->create(PatientFilterType::class, null, [
            'action' => $this->router->generate('patients_index'),
            'method' => Request::METHOD_GET,
        ]);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $patients = $this->patientFinder->matching($form->getData() ?: []);

        return $this->templating->renderResponse('patient/index.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'patients' => $patients,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Why is there a route annotation for `__invoke` that is empty?.
What is the lifecycle of this controller? I mean, when does Symfony creates the object and when executes the class to make use of `__invoke`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Empty `@Route` annotation means that there is nothing after main route of class which is `/patients`. `__invoke` is a magic PHP method that is executed when you call your class as a function (without providing any method).
So `__invoke` method is executed when you hit the route `/patients` or when you call your service from any code.